# Is it possible to loop into two different lists in the same playbook (Ansible)?

Tags: list, loops, ansible

I'm writing a Playbook Ansible and I want to loop into two different lists.
I now that I can use `with_items` to loop in a list, but can I use `with_items` twice in the same playbook?

Here is what I want to do:

```yaml
- name: Deploy the network in fabric 1 and fabric 2
  tags: [merged]
  role_network:
    config:
    - net_name: "{{ networkName }}"
      vrf_name: "{{ vrf }}"
      net_id: 30010
      net_template: "{{ networkTemplate }}"
      net_extension_template: "{{ networkExtensionTemplate }}"
      vlan_id: "{{ vlan }}"
      gw_ip_subnet: "{{ gw }}"
      attach: "{{ item }}"
      deploy: false
    fabric: "{{ item }}"
    state: merged
  with_items:
  - "{{ attachs }}"
    "{{ fabric }}"
  register: networks
```

So for the first call, I want to use the playbook with `fabric[0]` and `attachs[0]`.
For the second call, I want to use the playbook with `fabric[1]` and `attachs[1]`.
And so on...

Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking to achieve is what was [`with_together`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#with-together) and that is, now, [recommanded](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#migrating-from-with-x-to-loop) to achieve with the [`zip`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#zip-and-zip-longest-filters) filter.

So: `loop: "{{ attachs | zip(fabric) | list }}"`.

Where the element of the first list (`attachs`) would be `item.0` and the element of the second list (`fabric`) would be `item.1`.

```yaml
- name: Deploy the network in fabric 1 and fabric 2
  tags: [merged]
  role_network:
    config:
    - net_name: "{{ networkName }}"
      vrf_name: "{{ vrf }}"
      net_id: 30010
      net_template: "{{ networkTemplate }}"
      net_extension_template: "{{ networkExtensionTemplate }}"
      vlan_id: "{{ vlan }}"
      gw_ip_subnet: "{{ gw }}"
      attach: "{{ item.0 }}"
      deploy: false
    fabric: "{{ item.1 }}"
    state: merged
  loop: "{{ attachs | zip(fabric) | list }}"
  register: networks
```